Dynamics of the volatility process in the Heston model $d\sqrt{V_t}$
The Heston model's volatility process has the following dynamics:
$$dV_t=\kappa(\theta - V_t)dt+\sigma\sqrt{V_t}dW_t$$
and with that I am looking to derive the dynamics of $\sqrt{V_t}$, which I know to be a Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process that looks like this according to Wikipedia.
$$d\sqrt{V_t}=-\theta \sqrt{V_t}dt + \delta dW_t$$
But my variables seem to be uncooperative in my attempts so far...
I start by applying Ito's lemma to $f(x)=\sqrt{V_t}$ to get $$d\sqrt{V_t}=\left(\frac{\kappa (\theta - V_t)}{2\sqrt{V_t}} + \frac{\sigma^2}{8\sqrt{V_t}}\right)dt+\frac{\sigma}{2}dW_t$$
Then rewriting this expression, I obtain
$$ = \left[\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{V_t}}\right)\left(\frac{\kappa \theta}{2}-\frac{\sigma^2}{8}\right)-\sqrt{V_t}\left(\frac{\kappa}{2}\right)\right]dt + \frac{\sigma}{2}dW_t$$
With this expression, finally, I restrict $4\kappa\theta=\sigma^2$ so that the first terms fall off and we are left with a process that has the correct form of a O-U process, however the drift coefficient depends on $\kappa$ and not on $\theta$ as I expected.
$$d\sqrt{V_t}=-\frac{\kappa}{2}\sqrt{V_t}dt+\frac{\sigma}{2}dB_t$$

Where in WP they caim that?

I briefly googled the Heston model, but I couldn't find a reliable source discussing the equation for $\mathrm{d}\sqrt{V_t}$. Since your computation seems correct, I believe that whoever wrote down the equation for $\mathrm{d}\sqrt{V_t}$ in the Wikipedia article made a mistake, or simply did not care about the name of the symbol.

Related.

@KurtG. The second equation on the Heston Model's Wikipedia

Wikipedia assumes that the square-root follows a OU process and says then that $V_t$ follows a CIR process. You seem to be going in the other direction?

@Pedro Yes, that's correct. I'm trying to get to the square root process given the full volatility process. It's an exercise in a finance book I'm reading

Then why are you expecting it to match the result if you're going in the opposite direction? Notice that since $4\kappa \theta = \sigma^2$, $\kappa$ is a function of $\theta$, so you got something that does depend on $\theta$ (and $\sigma$) in the drift.

@Pedro I don't see any reason why I shouldn't get the same result going in either direction. The variables $\theta$ and $\kappa$ have specific interpretations under the model. $\theta$ is the long term mean of $V_t$ and $\kappa$ is the rate of mean reversion, so it doesn't make much sense to me to have them change places

No. You cannot go in both directions. The general CIR SDE is notoriously a lot less tractable than the OU SDE. Financial mathematicians have known that for decades.

@Kob This seems a bit naive. You seem to want to prove that $X_t$  follows a CIR process if and only if $\sqrt{X_t}$ follows an OU process, but from your calculation this is false already for general parameters!

@Pedro I am only looking for conditions on $\theta, \kappa, \sigma$ for which $\sqrt{V_t}$ is OU
